# Getting a footer to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, position, footer, spacing

So I know that there are other results here that are for this question, however I have a relatively "finished" code which I don't want to mess with too much if I can avoid it.

Basically I have everything on my website looking just the way I want it to, except that on larger displays the footer doesn't stick to the bottom of the screen, and there is this big ugly gap between my footer and the bottom of the screen.

Below are my index and css files. The footer element has been jostled around between the end tags, to no effect. I had it outside of my main body of content and tried bottom: 0; with position: absolute; and it just caused the right end of the footer to shoot off outside of the width I specified in my container.

```css
.header,
.navBar,
.pageTitle {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #006464;
}
html,
body,
#container {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
footer {
  background-color: #006400;
}
nav,
h1,
h2 {
  font-family: arial;
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
nav a {
  color: white;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
#container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#navBar {
  background-color: #228B22;
  padding: 10px;
}
#signUp {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
}
#welcomeFont {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: arial;
}
.header {
  background-color: #006400;
  padding: 20px;
}
.headerAnchor {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.table {
  background: #006400;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.tableData {
  font-size: 19px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
  opacity: .75;
}
.resizeAbout {
  max-height: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.resizeHome {
  max-height: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.resizePhotos {
  max-height: 40%;
  max-width: 40%;
}
.pageTitle {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 25px 0px;
}
.poetryAuthor {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-style: italic;
}
.poetryCaptions {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      <h1 class="header"><a class="headerAnchor" href="index.html">TheSingularEffect.Com</a></h1>
    </header>

    <nav id="navBar">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="music.html">Music</a>
      <a href="photos.html">Photos</a>
      <a href="poetry.html">Poetry</a>
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
    </nav>



    <h2 class="pageTitle">
    Get the Full Effect!
  </h2>

    <img class="resizeHome" src="image/homepage.jpg" alt="home page image">
    <h3 id="welcomeFont">
    Welcome to the home of The Singular Effect!  
  </h3>
    <br>

    <form>
      <span id="signUp">Sign up for our newsletter!</span>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="emailaddress" value="Email Address">
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

  </div>

  <footer>
    &copy; 2016, Chris Hughes - SNHU
  </footer>


</body>
```

Comment: Would `position: fixed` work?

Comment: No, it did work for a while but the problem is that it appears on the screen on page load, and sometimes over top of content that I have already on the screen. I just want the thing to stay at the bottom of the screen, below whatever content I happen to have on that page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using css-tables. I tested it and seems to work as requested. The footer also expands if you add content to it.

Under `body` add

```
margin:auto;
display:table;
```

and under `footer`

```
display:table-row;
position:fixed;
width:1000px;
bottom: 0;
```

Also in this case you should probably remove the `margin` from the `#container`  as it is defined in the `body` already.

Where I learned the trick: http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero#sticky-footer

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem to work on Firefox so some other way would be better.

Comment: I appreciate the effort. However when I did all of this, the result was that the footer didn't go to the bottom of the page (there is still a huge gap), there is no longer a gap between the footer and the bottom of my content (it's just stuck on the elements now), and the footer no longer matches the width of the navigation bar/header area. The goal is to make it stick to the bottom, even if there isn't enough content to fill the page on a large display.

Comment: Made some changes, any improvement?

Comment: It did help with the width.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header,
.navBar,
.pageTitle {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #006464;
}
html,
body,
#container {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
footer {
  background-color: #006400;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
nav,
h1,
h2 {
  font-family: arial;
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
nav a {
  color: white;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
#container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
#navBar {
  background-color: #228B22;
  padding: 10px;
}
#signUp {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
}
#welcomeFont {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: arial;
}
.header {
  background-color: #006400;
  padding: 20px;
}
.headerAnchor {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.table {
  background: #006400;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.tableData {
  font-size: 19px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
  opacity: .75;
}
.resizeAbout {
  max-height: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.resizeHome {
  max-height: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.resizePhotos {
  max-height: 40%;
  max-width: 40%;
}
.pageTitle {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 25px 0px;
}
.poetryAuthor {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-style: italic;
}
.poetryCaptions {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Home - The Singular Effect</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      <h1 class="header"><a class="headerAnchor" hreF="index.html">TheSingularEffect.Com</a></h1>
    </header>

    <nav id="navBar">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="music.html">Music</a>
      <a href="photos.html">Photos</a>
      <a href="poetry.html">Poetry</a>
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
    </nav>



    <h2 class="pageTitle">
        Get the Full Effect!
      </h2>

    <img class="resizeHome" src="image/homepage.jpg" alt="home page image">
    <h3 id="welcomeFont">
        Welcome to the home of The Singular Effect!
      </h3> 
    <br>

    <form>
      <span id="signUp">Sign up for our newsletter!</span> 
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="emailaddress" value="Email Address">
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

    <footer>
      &copy; 2016, Chris Hughes - SNHU
    </footer>

  </div>



</body>
```

Comment: Copy and paste that to a new page and see if it is what you want. You have an issue with the #content div being 100vh and then declared 100% min height.

I stuck the footer into the content div then made it absolute to the content div.

Comment: Okay so I tried this and it actually is the closest I have gotten to making my website work. Here is the only problem: I have 4 other pages, and 3 of them have content which goes all the way to the bottom of the page and it looks like it's merging with the footer. I tried adding on my "about" page an additional table row and the footer expanded with it, but it's still glued to the bottom of the last element. I have tried adding top margin to the footer, and it didn't do anything.

Comment: Update: I was able to rectify the issue by adding an empty <div> with a height of 50px in between the footer and the last element on both of those pages. While this is working, it feels like a work-around and I am still not sure what is causing the footer to smash into the other elements like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
I added 1 more div to target all the body content except footer so I can set the height for that element. Here are code that works:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<! Must have tables, forms, multimedia, and links >
<head>
    <title>Home - The Singular Effect</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`enter code here`
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
               margin: 0px;
               padding: 0px;
            }

            body {
                font-size: 20px;
                background-color: #006464;
            }

            html, body, #container {
              height: 100%;
              margin: 0;
            }

            footer {
                margin-top: 50px;
                background-color: #006400;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
                bottom: 0;
            }


            nav, h1, h2 {
                font-family: arial;
            }

            nav a:hover {
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
            }

            nav a {
                color: white;
            }

            h2 {
                text-align: center;
                background-color: white;
            }

            #container {
                width: 1000px;
                margin: auto;
                min-height: 100%;

            }


            #navBar {
                background-color: #228B22;
                padding: 10px;

            }

            #signUp {
                color: white;
                font-size: 20px;
                font-family: arial;
            }


            #welcomeFont {
                color: white;
                font-size: 25px;
                font-family: arial;
            }


            .header {
                background-color: #006400;
                padding: 20px;
            }


            .headerAnchor {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
            }

            .table {
                background: #006400;
                max-width: 100%;
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-spacing: 10px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }

            .tableData {
                font-size: 19px;
                background: white;
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 8px;
                opacity: .75;
            }


            .resizeAbout{
                max-height: 50%;
                max-width: 50%;
                margin-top: 50px;
                margin-bottom: 50px;

            }

            .resizeHome{
                max-height: 50%;
                max-width: 50%;
                margin-top: 50px;
            }

            .resizePhotos{
                max-height: 40%;
                max-width: 40%;

            }

            .pageTitle {
                padding-bottom: 0px;
                box-shadow: 0px 8px 25px 0px;
            }


            .poetryAuthor {
                color: white;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-family: arial;
                font-style: italic;
            }

            .poetryCaptions {
                margin-top: 50px;
                color: white;
                font-size: 25px;
                font-family: arial;
            }

            .bodyContetExceptFooter{
                padding: 20px;
              min-height: 90%;
              margin: 0 auto -50px;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <div class="bodyContetExceptFooter">
        <header>
            <h1 class="header"><a class="headerAnchor" href="index.html">TheSingularEffect.Com</a></h1>
        </header>
        <div id="navBar">
        <nav>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                <a href="music.html">Music</a>
                <a href="photos.html">Photos</a>
                <a href="poetry.html">Poetry</a>
                <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </nav>  
        </div>

        <div id="divContent">
            <h2 class="pageTitle">
                Get the Full Effect!
            </h2>

            <img class="resizeHome" src="image/homepage.jpg" alt="home page image">
            <h3 id="welcomeFont">
                Welcome to the home of The Singular Effect!
            </h3> <br>


            <form>
                <span id="signUp">Sign up for our newsletter!</span> <br>
                <input type="text" name="emailaddress" value="Email Address">
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            &copy; 2016, Chris Hughes - SNHU
        </footer>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `relative` positioning on `body`, `absolute` positioning on `footer` and position it to `left: 0; bottom 0;`, also add `width: 100%;` to `footer` to fill full width of `body`.

One last thing is to add `padding-bottom: 23px;` to body to avoid `footer` hiding content when the height of browser is less than your content.

```css
.header,
.navBar,
.pageTitle {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #006464;
  position: relative; /* added */
  padding-bottom: 23px; /* added, where 23px is the height of the footer */
}
html,
body,
#container {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
footer {
  background-color: #006400;
  position: absolute; /* added */
  bottom: 0; /* added */
  left: 0; /* added */
  width: 100%; /* added */
}
nav,
h1,
h2 {
  font-family: arial;
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
nav a {
  color: white;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
#container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#navBar {
  background-color: #228B22;
  padding: 10px;
}
#signUp {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
}
#welcomeFont {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: arial;
}
.header {
  background-color: #006400;
  padding: 20px;
}
.headerAnchor {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.table {
  background: #006400;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.tableData {
  font-size: 19px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
  opacity: .75;
}
.resizeAbout {
  max-height: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.resizeHome {
  max-height: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.resizePhotos {
  max-height: 40%;
  max-width: 40%;
}
.pageTitle {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 25px 0px;
}
.poetryAuthor {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-style: italic;
}
.poetryCaptions {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      <h1 class="header"><a class="headerAnchor" href="index.html">TheSingularEffect.Com</a></h1>
    </header>

    <nav id="navBar">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="music.html">Music</a>
      <a href="photos.html">Photos</a>
      <a href="poetry.html">Poetry</a>
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
    </nav>



    <h2 class="pageTitle">
    Get the Full Effect!
  </h2>

    <img class="resizeHome" src="image/homepage.jpg" alt="home page image">
    <h3 id="welcomeFont">
    Welcome to the home of The Singular Effect!  
  </h3>
    <br>

    <form>
      <span id="signUp">Sign up for our newsletter!</span>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="emailaddress" value="Email Address">
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

  </div>

  <footer>
    &copy; 2016, Chris Hughes - SNHU
  </footer>


</body>
```